# Structuring a complex query to match rows in a log file

Tags: mysql

I have a log table in MySQL which looks like this:

```
mysql> describe logtable;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| logdate  | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| host     | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| action   | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user     | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| org      | varchar(100)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| location | varchar(1000)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and here's a sample of its contents (not all fields shown):

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
|    id    |       logdate       | action |         user         | location |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
| 13933768 | 2017-01-03 08:42:25 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 13934110 | 2017-01-03 08:58:38 | login  | user2@somewhere.com  | place2   |
| 13935532 | 2017-01-03 11:02:31 | logout | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 13935622 | 2017-01-03 11:11:25 | logout | user2@somewhere.com  | place2   |
| 13935772 | 2017-01-03 11:27:27 | login  | user3@somewhere.com  | place3   |
| 13935942 | 2017-01-03 11:52:16 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13936217 | 2017-01-03 12:25:08 | logout | user3@somewhere.com  | place3   |
| 13936293 | 2017-01-03 12:33:16 | logout | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13937676 | 2017-01-03 15:33:59 | login  | user3@somewhere.com  | place5   |
| 13937859 | 2017-01-03 15:51:53 | logout | user3@somewhere.com  | place5   |
| 13942394 | 2017-01-04 08:31:26 | login  | user5@somewhere.com  | place2   |
| 13943946 | 2017-01-04 09:46:04 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13944372 | 2017-01-04 10:17:25 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13944373 | 2017-01-04 10:17:27 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13944374 | 2017-01-04 10:17:29 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13944375 | 2017-01-04 10:19:22 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13944575 | 2017-01-04 10:36:48 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13946830 | 2017-01-04 14:56:36 | login  | user6@somewhere.com  | place7   |
| 13947791 | 2017-01-04 16:41:26 | logout | user5@somewhere.com  | place2   |
| 13947795 | 2017-01-04 16:41:59 | login  | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13948181 | 2017-01-04 17:19:19 | logout | user4@somewhere.com  | place7   |
| 13948200 | 2017-01-04 17:22:18 | logout | user4@somewhere.com  | place4   |
| 13948201 | 2017-01-04 17:22:18 | logout | user4@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13948824 | 2017-01-04 20:23:15 | login  | user7@somewhere.com  | place8   |
| 13948870 | 2017-01-04 20:44:42 | logout | user7@somewhere.com  | place8   |
| 13949945 | 2017-01-05 02:26:35 | logout | user6@somewhere.com  | place7   |
| 13951697 | 2017-01-05 08:49:37 | login  | user8@somewhere.com  | place6   |
| 13951863 | 2017-01-05 08:56:37 | login  | user9@somewhere.com  | place9   |
| 13951886 | 2017-01-05 08:57:06 | login  | user10@somewhere.com | place9   |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
```

And I would like to produce a table showing each user's cumulative time logged in to the various locations. In theory, the `login` and `logout` entries for each person & place combination should be in pairs, but various things like client glitches and network oddities sometimes means there is a mismatch. It's also possible to log in to a second place before logging out of the first place, so the pairs may overlap each other. In addition, the pairs may not match in one of the following ways:

- a `login` event with no matching `logout`
- a `logout` event with no matching `login` (sounds strange, but the software logs interrupted logins like this
- multiple `login` events (retries) with only one corresponding `logout`

I've got so far by joining the table to itself on the `user` and `location`, and subtracting `logout` times from `login` times. I'm also ensuring the id of the `logout` event is higher than the `login` event, as they're always increasing. But since there could be multiple entries, I'm getting all combinations. Take this simple example:

### Example 1

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
|    id    |       logdate       | action |         user         | location |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
| 1        | 2017-01-03 08:42:25 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 2        | 2017-01-03 11:02:31 | logout | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 3        | 2017-01-03 11:27:27 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 4        | 2017-01-03 12:25:08 | logout | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
```

My naive approach:

```
select * from logtable as t1
join logtable as t2
on t1.user = t2.user and t1.location = t2.location
and t1.action = 'login' and t2.action = 'logout'
and t2.id > t1.id
```

gives me 3 results: ids 1→2, 1→4 and 3→4. And since it might *also* look like this:

## Example 2

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
|    id    |       logdate       | action |         user         | location |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
| 1        | 2017-01-03 08:42:25 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 2        | 2017-01-03 08:43:35 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 3        | 2017-01-03 08:44:45 | login  | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
| 4        | 2017-01-03 12:25:08 | logout | user1@somewhere.com  | place1   |
+----------+---------------------+--------+----------------------+----------+
```

which is 3 attempts at login before it succeeded, followed by a logout, I should only get 1 result not 3, and the required answer is the difference between id 3 and id 4.

I can kind of describe what I'm after, but not translate it into SQL—at least not without multiple nested SELECTs which just run for hours (the log file is 8500 lines).

1. For each matching `user` and `location`, find the *last* of any logins and the  *first* of any logouts where the logout is *after* the login.
2. Calculate the time difference between those 2 events
3. Ignore logins that have no matching logout and vice versa
4. Sum the cumulative time per user

In Example 1 above, that should give 2 'login / logout' events (ids 1→2 = 2:20:06 and 3→4 = 0:57:41) summed into 1 output row = 3:17:47, and for Example 2 it should give a single 'event' (ids 3→4 = 3:40:23) summed into 1 row.

Comment: Please replace the id's in the examples with the id's from the source table.

Comment: Why? Those rows are invented to illustrate the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do the trick:

`SELECT
    MIN(logdate_logout) AS logdate_logout,logdate_login,user,location,id_login,id_logout
FROM (
    SELECT 
        MAX(logdate_login) AS logdate_login, logdate_logout,user,location,id_login,id_logout
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1.id       AS id_login,
            t1.logdate  AS logdate_login,
            t1.user,
            t1.location,
            t2.id       AS id_logout,
            t2.logdate  AS logdate_logout
        FROM logtable AS t1
        JOIN logtable AS t2 
        ON (t1.user = t2.user AND t1.location = t2.location AND t1.action = 'login' AND t2.action = 'logout' AND t2.id > t1.id)
        ORDER BY t1.logdate,t2.logdate
    ) results_naive_approach
    GROUP BY logdate_logout,user,location
) inner_query
GROUP BY logdate_login,user,location`

this will make sure you only have the logins that are right before the matching logouts and the logouts that are right after the matching logins

Comment: login and logout are values in the rows—I'm not sure I follow what I should be putting in the surround query you posted. Are they just literals? I updated the question with my actual naive SQL to show what I currently have.

Comment: I updated my answer, take a look at it now. I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks—much clearer what to do, but when I run that query, I get "SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'". It's running on MySQL version 5.0.95 if that is relevant? I've put the output from 'describe' in the question, in case the additional fields that are in the table matter (I don't think they should).

Comment: @dsl101 that's because in the previous version I renamed them, but now it should be working.

Comment: Tx. There's a trailing comma after logdate_logout which threw me for a while, but now the query is running, and I can see it's returning the correct number of rows for the test data I have, so many thanks. I can add the duration stuff from here. Woohoo!